# Jenkins Job DSL for timestamps is not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

I am working with Jenkins Job DSL and can not seem to get a couple of the tags to work.  One of those is *timestamps()*.  In each of my jobs we have checked off the following field

> Add timestamps to the Console Output

and I believe this translates to *timestamps()*.  When I run the seed job to create the job *Add timestamps to the Console Output* is not checked.

My code:

```
wrappers {
    preBuildCleanup {
        deleteDirectories(false)
        cleanupParameter()
    }
    timeout {
        absolute(10)
    }
    timestamps()
    colorizeOutput("String colorMap = 'xterm'")     
}
```

The DSL was created with the *XML Job To DSL* plugin for Jenkins which added that field.

I may have misinterpreted something here but it seems pretty straight forward.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've google quite a bit but have not found anything that might help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It required a restart of the Jenkins instance and now it is displaying as expected.